# ArcView: Trim polyline, that is shorter than specific dangle length (alternative to tool: Trim Line)?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, network, topology, line, et-geowizards

I am looking for a way to trim dangles from a polyline shape, that are shorter than a specific length like the [Trim Line Tool for ArcEditor and ArcInfo](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001v00000008000000.htm), but with ArcView-License.

I already discover, that the ET geowizards-Toolbox has a similar tool called "Clean Dangling Nodes". Unfortunately this Tool also create new features where other features are closer than the specified dangling tolerance. You can see this in the following picture:

[Result (orange) of the tool Clean Dangling Nodes compared to the input data (blue)](https://mediacru.sh/AboosXkgT0r8)

Where the tool works like I want to is marked with green circles. But there are several situations where the tool creates new features (what I don't want) that are marked with red circles.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you try the tool using smaller tolerances?  Alternately you might use the Export Nodes to identify the dangline ones, and then use that point layer to select line segments (Select by Location) to delete.  You might need to do this several times.

Comment: @johns: Thanks, the alternative way with Export Nodes will do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I could solve the problem doing the following steps (thanks to @johns, who suggested me this idea):

1. Create a copy of your street data.
2. Use ETgeowizards tool "Clean Pseudo Nodes", if your street data has pseudo nodes.
3. Use ETgeowizards tool "Export Nodes" to export nodes and export only dangling nodes.
4. Select street parts, that intersects with the dangling nodes with "Select by Location"
5. Optional: you can sub-select street dangles with a specific length with "Select by Attribute"
6. Delete selected features.

You can also implement this workflow in Python.